# Can I dispatch an event with no data specified in Alpine.js?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Is it possible to use `$dispatch` without specifying data in the event body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! As stated in the [docs](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/dispatch), you can simply not include any arguments after the event name:

```html
<div x-data @notify="alert('Hello World!')">
    <button @click="$dispatch('notify')">
      Notify
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: If this does not work, append `x-data` to the parent div attributes. I am pretty sure Alpine won't work if it doesn't have an `x-data` attribute. It doesn't need any data to function though.

Comment: Good spot @Yinci! I made an optimistic assumption that it would sit inside a tag with `x-data` already defined. I've updated, thanks!